# ElasticSearch CronJob weird behaviour

Tags: elasticsearch, cron, elastic-stack, minikube, kubernetes-cronjob

I've implemented an example of **ELK stack** to centralize logging of my k8s cluster using **minikube**.
I've also deployed a cron job to delete 1 day old logs **every hour** as title of example.

Because it's scheduled at the beginning of each hour (schedule: "0 * * * *"), I've noticed that at the first application, when the new hour began, the  **/data** folder of elasticsearch passed from **14M** to **2.1M** instantaneously, sign that the cronjob just deleted old file logs.

The fact is, after some bunches of seconds, the **/data** folder passed from **2.1M** to **2.7M** and then back down to **2.4M** like logs were deleted every 15-20 seconds and not at the begin of each hour. If I continue monitoring the **/data** folder, it's going up and down continuously.

Anyway **/logs** folder is 13M and **has grown up fastly** in some days but the cron job didn't delete its files at all. **Is also that normal?**

This is the basic logging pod I've deployed in **default** namespace:

https://k8s.io/examples/debug/counter-pod.yaml

This is the **elastic search deployment** deployed in **logging** namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-pvc # name of PVC essential for identifying the storage data 
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging 
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---      
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch-logging
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.3.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 2400Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 2350Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: db
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: elasticsearch-logging
          mountPath: /data
        env:
        - name: "NAMESPACE"
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MINIMUM_MASTER_NODES
          value: "1"
      initContainers:
      - image: registry.hub.docker.com/library/alpine:3.6
        command: ["/sbin/sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        name: elasticsearch-logging-init
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      volumes:
      - name: elasticsearch-logging
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: elasticsearch-pvc   
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: db
  selector:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
```

This is the **cronjob** deployed in **logging** namespace:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-curator
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
spec:
  schedule: "0 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          name: elasticsearch-curator
          labels:
            k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
        spec:
          restartPolicy: "Never"
          containers:
          - name: ingestor
            image: python:3.6-alpine
            args: ["sh", "-c", "pip install elasticsearch-curator && curator_cli --host elasticsearch-logging delete_indices --filter_list '[{\"filtertype\":\"age\",\"source\":\"creation_date\",\"direction\":\"older\",\"unit\":\"days\",\"unit_count\":1},{\"filtertype\":\"pattern\",\"kind\":\"prefix\",\"value\":\"logstash\"}]' || true"]
      backoffLimit: 1
```

What's wrong with my cron job?

Comment: Have you been checking pod's logs and if the pod was restarted? what does `kubectl get pods <your logging pod> ?

Comment: It hasn't ever restarted. It keeps going. When I tried to delete the curator the ElasticSearch pod /data folder remained crazy a lot of up and down variation of folder dimension.

Comment: Have you been checking pod's logs ?